# Blackberry Webworks app class not found error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

When I try to deploying my blackberry app on a blackberry device i am getting following error while i run the app: class net.rim.device.api.compress. gzipoutputstream not found
Any idea why i am getting this error ?
I am a newbie and hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK are you using?  I believe net.rim.device.api.compress is a Java class, but you've tagged your post as blackberry-webworks which uses JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to create apps.

If this is a WebWorks app you're making, then you cannot use a Java API like this.

You could however create a custom extension to expose this functionality.  You can learn more about creating extensions for the BlackBerry Smartphone over here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_javascript_extensions_1866976_11.html